# ScaffoldMessenger not displaying SnackBar, not issues in debug console

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement a password reset feature using Firebase where if a PlatformException error occurs, then a SnackBar shows what the error is. However, the SnackBar is not showing despite there being an PlatformException error. However, the console does not show any issues with the SnackBar implementation. Any insights would be appreciated!

```
class ResetPasswordScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ResetPasswordState createState() => _ResetPasswordState();
}

class _ResetPasswordState extends State<ResetPasswordScreen> {
  final _auth = auth.FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String _email = '';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: FractionallySizedBox(
        widthFactor: 1,
        heightFactor: .5,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
          child: Card(
            color: Colors.white,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Scaffold(
                resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                appBar: PreferredSize(
                  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(40),
                  child: AppBar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    elevation: 0,
                    leading: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back,
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      'Password Reset',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        fontSize: 28,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                body: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        resetEmail(context),
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                          child: resetButton(),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  TextFormField resetEmail(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      cursorColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
          return 'Please enter a valid email';
        }
        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (value) {
        _email = value.trim();
      },
    );
  }

  TextButton resetButton() {
    return TextButton(
      child: Text('Send request'),
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        primary: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        textStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20,
        ),
      ),
      onPressed: () => _submitRequest(),
    );
  }

  void _submitRequest() async {
    if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      return;
    }
    _formKey.currentState.save();
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    try {
      await _auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: _email);
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    } on PlatformException catch (err) {
      var message = 'Please check your email';
      if (err.message != null) {
        message = err.message;
      }
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text(message),
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
        ),
      );
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can une this package for the easiest way of showing snackbars and more https://pub.dev/packages/get

Comment: @EbenezerNikabou I don't think it is a good idea to add Getx if you only want the snackbar feature.

Comment: it's working here, try `flutter clean` and rebuild again

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with the Snackbar code (I tested it and it works properly). The problem is propably that the showSnackBar function never gets called.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a context issue. I needed a builder function for the Scaffold to have a proper context for the snackBar.